# How do I write a program to output a triangle of numbers in Java?

Tags: java, loops

I need help. My assignment is to write a Java program using nested loops to print out the following output pattern:

```
                   1 
                 1 2 1 
                1 2 4 2 1 
              1 2 4 8 4 2 1 
            1 2 4 8 16 8 4 2 1 
          1 2 4 8 16 32 16 8 4 2 1 
       1 2 4 8 16 32 64 32 16 8 4 2 1 
    1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
```

---

```
//pattern1
for(int outer=1;outer<=6;outer++) // outer loop controls number of rows
{
    for(int inner=1;inner<=outer; inner++) // another loop to control number of numbers in each row.
    {
        System.out.print(inner);
    }
    System.out.println(); // move the cursor from the end of the current line to the beggiing to the next line
}

//pattern 2
for(int outer =1; outer<=6 ; outer++) //outer loop controls number of rows
{
    //3-1 create spaces before numbers.
    for(int space=1; space<=6-outer; space++ ) //group controls number of spaces
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    //3-2 print out real numbers.
    for(int inner=1;inner<=outer; inner++) // another loop to control number of numbers in each row.
    {
        System.out.print(inner);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Those two codes are back to back, but I do not understand how I would make the numbers `2 4 8 16` etc show up, and put them back to back.

What's wrong with my code? Is there a better way of doing this in Java?

Comment: I like how this is protected, but has a negative voting number.

Answer (score 10):

A simple version with bit shifting and static column size / padding - could be improved by using `Math.getExponent()` for dynamically repeating spaces and format `%3d` ...

```
public static void f(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int l = n - i; l > 0; l--) { // padding for symmetry
            System.out.print("    "); 
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) { // "left side" of pyramid
            System.out.printf("%3d ", 1 << j); 
        }
        for (int k = i - 1; k >= 0; k--) { // "right side" of pyramid
            System.out.printf("%3d ", 1 << k); 
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
                              1 
                          1   2   1 
                      1   2   4   2   1 
                  1   2   4   8   4   2   1 
              1   2   4   8  16   8   4   2   1 
          1   2   4   8  16  32  16   8   4   2   1 
      1   2   4   8  16  32  64  32  16   8   4   2   1 
  1   2   4   8  16  32  64 128  64  32  16   8   4   2   1
```

Answer (score 5):

You're going to use a nested loop with an if statement controlling the output.

This code should help you with your formatting.  You'll have to figure out how to add the || so that it flips the triangle and how to format your print statements so it looks like that.

```
int totalWidth = 8;
for (int row = 1; row <= totalWidth; row++) {
    for (int col = 1; col <= totalWidth; col++) {
      if (col <= totalWidth - row) {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }else {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
```

It will output

```
       *
      **
     ***
    ****
   *****
  ******
 *******
********
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class pyramid

    public static void f(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int l = n - i; l > 0; l--) { // padding for symmetry
            System.out.print("    "); 
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) { // "left side" of pyramid
            System.out.printf("%3d ", 1 << j); 
        }
        for (int k = i - 1; k >= 0; k--) { // "right side" of pyramid
            System.out.printf("%3d ", 1 << k); 
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```